# How to get docker memory and cpu utilization details for past

Tags: docker

How to get docker memory and cpu utilization details for past 1 week/month data ?

docker stats - command will give current data

Answer (score 1):

You may try [Swarmpit](https://github.com/swarmpit/swarmpit), but this requires you to run Docker in [swarm mode](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/).

Quick insecure demo:

```
docker swarm init
git clone https://github.com/swarmpit/swarmpit
docker stack deploy -c swarmpit/docker-compose.yml swarmpit
```

This will deploy the Swarmpit stack, which contains 4 services. Each service has one task, and each task carries a container.

So you have 4 containers. To see a graph for their memory usage, go to http://localhost:888, create your admin account, click on `Tasks` on the left menu, then click on a task. Scroll down and you will see some graphs:

[image: swarmpit screenshot showing CPU and memory usage graphs]

Answer (score 0):

Container storage is ephemeral so unless you are backing up those stats with some logging service, you lose them every time the container gets redeployed.
Take a look at something like [datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/blog/how-to-collect-docker-metrics/#stats-command)

Comment: Can I somehow get stats for the whole time of container life?